# Adding rows to tbody of a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, rows

I am trying to add rows to the `tbody` of a table. But I am having issues with achieving that. Firstly, the function where everything takes place is called on change of a dropdown from a html page. I created a `tr` string containing all the `td` inside that containing the html elements, text and other stuff. But when I am trying to add that generated row to the table using:

```
$(newRowContent).appendTo("#tblEntAttributes tbody");
```

I am encountering an error. The name of the table is `tblEntAttributes` and I am trying to add it to the `tbody`.

Actually what's happening is jQuery is unable to get `tblEntAttributes` as an html element. But I can access it using `documemt.getElementById("tblEntAttributes");`

Is there any way I can achieve this by adding rows to the `tbody` of the table. Maybe a bypass or something.

Here's the entire code:

```
var newRowContent = "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + chkboxId + "\" value=\"" + chkboxValue + "\"></td><td>" + displayName + "</td><td>" + logicalName + "</td><td>" + dataType + "</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" name=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" value=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\"></td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" name=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" value=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\"></td></tr>";

$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

One thing I forgot to mention is the function where this code is written is actually the success callback function for a ajax call. I am able to access the table using `document.getElementById("tblEntAttributes")` but for some reason `$(#tblEntAttributes)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you post some snippet of your DOM (mostly the table in question)

Comment: $('#Table1 > tbody')

Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763006/how-to-get-the-tbody-element-of-a-table-using-jquery/6763036#6763036

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have never ever come across such a strange problem like this! o.O

Do you know what the problem was? $ isn't working. I tried the same code with jQuery like `jQuery("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);` and it works like a charm!

No idea why this strange problem occurs!

Comment: You should read up about jQuery.noConflict().  It could be that you are using other libraries that also use the $ alias http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 123):

`("#tblEntAttributes tbody")`

needs to be

`$("#tblEntAttributes tbody")`.

You are not selecting the element with the correct syntax

Here's an example of both

```
$(newRowContent).appendTo($("#tblEntAttributes"));
```

and

```
$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

working
http://jsfiddle.net/xW4NZ/

Comment: Inverting the syntax might be more readable: `$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);`.

Comment: I have added the code in the OP. It keeps giving the error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'append': object is null or undefined"

Comment: Are you putting those inside $(document).ready(function() {
   // some code here
 });  Could be that the code is running before the dom is ready which is why you are unable to select the element.  Found a similar error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173398/unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-appendchild-object-is-null-or-undefined

Comment: `$("#tblEntAttributes > tbody")` for direct child tbody?

Comment: @webNoob13 Yeah if you want to be more specific that should work too

Comment: in instances like this jquery seems so convenient but I keep being told on S.O. "Use vanilla JS because it's better than what it was when jQuery was created/first released."  What's your opinion on that?

Comment: @mLstudent33 I think it all depends on what you're doing.  It's not worth it to bring in a library if you're only doing simple things that can be done with vanilla JS.  If you're already using the library then you might as well use the tools provided by it to keep it consistent

Answer (score 42):

use this

```
$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an appendTo version using the html dropdown you mentioned. It inserts another row on "change".

```
$('#dropdown').on( 'change', function(e) {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>');
});
```

With an example for you to play with. Best of luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/xtHaF/12/

Answer (score 4):

As @wirey said `appendTo` should work, if not then you can try this:

```
$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

Answer (score 2):

With Lodash you can create a template and you can do that following way:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <table id="tblEntAttributes" class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                chkboxId
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               chkboxValue
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                displayName
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               logicalName
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                dataType
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="test">appendTo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And here goes the javascript:

```
        var count = 1;
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var compiledRow = _.template("<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"<%= chkboxId %>\" value=\"<%= chkboxValue %>\"></td><td><%= displayName %></td><td><%= logicalName %></td><td><%= dataType %></td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" name=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" value=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\"></td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" name=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\" value=\"chkAllPrimaryAttrs\"></td></tr>");
            document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                var ajaxData = { 'chkboxId': 'chkboxId-' + count, 'chkboxValue': 'chkboxValue-' + count, 'displayName': 'displayName-' + count, 'logicalName': 'logicalName-' + count, 'dataType': 'dataType-' + count };
                var tableRowData = compiledRow(ajaxData);
                $("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(tableRowData);
                count++;
            });
        });
```

Here it is in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xiqaloh/2/edit?js,output)